# How to remove last loop from foreach?

Tags: php, json

I grab json filtering with my own json. How to limit foreach for last loop?

```
    <?php
    
    $data = '{"page":1,
    "results":
    [{
    "gender": "male",
    "language":"English"
    
    },
    {
    "gender": "male",
    "language":"Jerman"
    },
    {
    "gender": "feamle",
    "language":"English"
      
    }]}';
    
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    
    foreach ($json['results'] as $r){
        
    if($r['language'] == "English")
    
    {
    echo $r['language']."},{\n";
    
    }
}
```

Output :

```
English},{

English},{
```

Expected output :

```
English},{
English
```

The point is how to remove / exclude last "},{" in the end of loop?

Comment: So you mean if there are two (or more) identical output values (both are English), then just display ONCE ?

Comment: Just igone about "English", i just want remove last "},{" at the end. Thanks

Comment: I see. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the total count of the result, and then if the output line is the last count then do not output the characters `},{`

So the codes (working) is:

```
 <?php
    
    $data = '{"page":1,
    "results":
    [{
    "gender": "male",
    "language":"English"
    
    },
    {
    "gender": "male",
    "language":"Jerman"
    },
    {
    "gender": "feamle",
    "language":"English"
      
    }]}';
    
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    
$totalcount=0;   

foreach ($json['results'] as $r){
if($r['language'] == "English")
{ $totalcount++; }      
}

$index=0;

foreach ($json['results'] as $r){
    if($r['language'] == "English")
    {
      $index++;  
      if ($index!=$totalcount)  {  
      echo $r['language']."},{\n"; }
      else {
      echo $r['language'];}
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it using *array_filter*, *array_column* and *implode*.

- *[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter)*- used to filter out all entries except ones that have `language: English`
- *[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)* - takes the filtered array and pulls out a single "column", `language`
- *[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)* - pulls the array back together into a string and joins each element with a separator, `},{\n`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20120eb9a9fdfbc3c0d29ea57036e7cf1d2d5409

```
<?php
    
$data = '{"page":1,
"results":
[{
"gender": "male",
"language":"English"

},
{
"gender": "male",
"language":"Jerman"
},
{
"gender": "feamle",
"language":"English"
  
}]}';

$json = json_decode($data, true);

// Filter out everything except entries that have English
$filtered = array_filter($json['results'], function($result){
    return $result['language'] === 'English';
});

// Pull out a specific "column" (`language`) from the array.
$languages = array_column($filtered, 'language');

// Use `implode` to join all the entries together.
// The separator will only be used between the elements. It will not be added to the end.
echo implode("},{\n", $languages);
```

But, the closet solution to your original idea is just to use a simple counter to determine which "loop" you're in and only output the separator if you're not in the final loop.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe18e8584320e680aa194a4faa6fe7edc31ed6ac

```
<?php

$data = '{"page":1,
"results":
[{
"gender": "male",
"language":"English"

},
{
"gender": "male",
"language":"Jerman"
},
{
"gender": "feamle",
"language":"English"

}]}';

$json = json_decode($data, true);

$totalCount = count($json);
$currentLoop = 0;

foreach ($json['results'] as $r) {

    $currentLoop++;
    
    if ($r['language'] == "English") {
        
        // Always output the language
        echo $r['language'];
        
        // But only output the separator if we're not in the final loop.
        // On the final loop, $currentLoop will equal $totalCount.
        if ($currentLoop < $totalCount) {
            echo "},{\n"   ;
        }
    }
}
```